# NerdTree - Adjust Open Windows to Equal Width

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Suppose I open two files in vim vertically.  If I then open nerdtree, nerdtree gets its columns from the leftmost window.  I'd prefer my two preexisting windows remain an equal size.  In other words, all existing windows should be adjusted for nerdtree - not just the leftmost.  How can this be done?  (I don't startup nerdtree when vim loads - I toggle it when I need it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the windows to be equal by entering `<c-w>=`

Comment: Thank you.  Here is the mapping I use for Nerdtree (in case anyone needs it).  This automatically resizes all the windows when NerdTree is toggled: `nnoremap <Leader>t :NERDTreeToggle<CR> <c-w>=`